# SvelteKit producing TypeError in generated file p.getQuestions()

Tags: typescript, typeerror, sveltekit

I have a SvelteKit project that was working fine. After a while I noticed it started spamming my console with this TypeError:

> main.tsx.8578f314.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: p.getQuestions is not a function
> at main.tsx.8578f314.js:5:61923 @ main.tsx.8578f314.js:5

The problem is that this is a Svelte generated file.
I tried going back to commits where I'm sure I did not have this error, but now the error appears there as well.

Could this be a config error? Has anyone seen something like this?

I'm using the default ts-config and svelte-config that gets generated with the svelte@latest project. The code does not show any errors or warnings.